# "Optional parameters should not be used" error thrown in SonarQube analysis

Tags: c#, sonarqube, optional-parameters

I'm getting error - "Optional parameters should not be used" in Sonar analysis for C# project. Actually in C# latest version we can define optional parameter but SonarQube analysis says Optional parameters should not be used. How can I solve this issue? I'm using latest SonarQube version 6.0.

Comment: Your question is like this : I getting some error, It is because of some `x`; how can i solve that? Definitely their may be someone ready to help you, please be clear about your issues help him to understand the issues

Answer (score 1):

You can either deactivate the rule on your SonarQube server or mark it as False Positive for your particular case but I would recommend you to have a look at why we created this rule before you deactivate it.
You can find more information about this rule on our [Rules website](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=csharpsquid%3AS2360) or on [Microsoft website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182135.aspx).

Comment: Rules website link mentioned in your reply is not working.

Comment: Hi Rasik, I just checked and both links are working from here (Switzerland). Could you check it is not your firewall?

Comment: I'm still not able to open it. Can you please send it to rasik.bapotra@capgemini.com.

Comment: Not sure if this will change something but I did it.